# Draw the derivative of a function

Tags: derivatives, graphing-functions

I am trying to draw the graph of the derivative of this function:

[image]

Since the function has a maximum at $x = 0$, the derivative at this point must be zero. In addition, the function is increasing up to $x = 0$ and decreasing from this value, so the derivative has $y> 0$ for $x <0$ and $y <0$ for $x> 0$. When $x$ tends to $+\infty$, the graph tends to zero, so $f'(x) = 0$. My problem is to understand the shape of the concavity, or if there is a concavity in the graph. The graph I made was as follows:

[image]

Could you tell me if the concavities and the shape of the graph are right and why do you have the concavities that way?

Comment: Looks good. Give your graph some scaling.

Comment: looks good, but notice that for values $x\to -\infty$, the derivative should tend to $+\infty$.

Comment: Maybe $f’$ should be concave up for $x\lt 0$, depending upon the sign of $f’’’$.

Comment: @Roger But for x$\rightarrow\,-\infty$, would the concavity be like this ("lying down"), or would it go with a concavity similar to that of x$^2$? Could you answer with your drawing please?

Comment: @CarmenGonzález as Tavish said, it should go "like $x^2$" up, because you can see that the first values for $f$ drawn on your graph have a very big, almost vertical slope.

Comment: Well, the graph skyrockets down for $x \to -\infty$.

Comment: @Roger Thank you for your help. I didn't understand what they meant by $f'''$. Could you explain it better, please? I don't understand the trick of $f'''$.

Comment: @newQOpenGLWidget Thanks for the answer. Could you explain in the answer, why we need $f'''$? I didn't understand the trick of using the third derivative.

Comment: Just like the derivative gives you the slope of a graph, the second derivative gives you the curvature of the original function. Thus the third derivative gives you the curvature of the first derivative (concave or convex).

Comment: Added it in the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much to everyone who commented. I realized the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your graph appears to look good. However, note that the derivative for values for $x \to -\infty$, the derivative does *not* reach an asymptote, as you assume, instead it goes to infinity. The slope is very big if $x \to -\infty$, as indicated by the graph.

So yes, it should grow "like $x^2$ up.", because the slope is very big. Additionally, the left side of the graph seems close to $y = ax^3 + 1$, whose derivative is $3ax^2$, a quadratic function.

---

The "trick" says things about the concavity of $f^\prime$. To find the concavity, you have to check the sign of second derivative of the function. In this case, the function is the first derivative of your original function. $(f^\prime)^{\prime \prime}$ = $f^{\prime \prime \prime}$.

Comment: I understand, thank you very much for your answer! I didn't have the function, I just had the graph and I tried to draw the derivative according to the graph of the function I had. But you're right, it resembles a cubic function and the derivative gives a quadratic, so it should be positioned upwards. Thank you for helping me understand the concavities.